# How was the band poisoned in 'The Lure'

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-lure

In the Polish film [*The Lure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lure_(2015_film)) the 3 members of the band, after throwing the girls in the river, appear to have been poisoned and they are then revived by a blonde woman. Was it ever explained in the film how they were poisoned and by whom? And what was the meaning of this scene?